# ag-grid last changed cell value is not detected in viewmodel

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I have my ag-grid options as follows. I am facing a problem that the last updated cell value is not getting detected. I mean, Lets say I have 8 columns in a row and I edit columns in an order, 1,2,3 and 4. The 4th updated column cell value is not getting detected in my view model.

If I change `stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus` as true, things are fine. But I have Jquery datepicker in one of my column and onSelect event is not getting fired for that. So I have to keep `stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus` to false.

Your help is much appreciated.

```
this.GridOptions = {singleClickEdit: true , stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus: false};
```

Comment: How are you checking when the cell value has changed?

Comment: this.gridApi.forEachNode(
      node => this.sterList.push(node.data)
    );  <- Like this.